# Authenticate only "admin" users registered with Firebase Auth

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions

I have an app that lets users sign in via email and password. The app has a feed with posts that need to be moderated. I have an admin react website that lets the moderators remove or keep posts. Right now any user can login and see the content, however I wanna make the login only available for admin users. I made my account "admin" using Admin SDK of Firebase.

I was thinking to make a Cloud Function which verifies whether the email is an admin and return true or false accordingly. Then authenticate the user normally using Firebase Auth. Is this secure enough?

Answer (score 6):

If you've [set a custom claim](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/custom-claims#set_and_validate_custom_user_claims_via_the_admin_sdk) marking the user as an application administrator, you can [check in your client-side code for the presence of that claim](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/custom-claims#access_custom_claims_on_the_client). You can then use the result of that to show the correct UI.

On the server/in the database security rules, you'll also want to check the presence of this admin claim before allow the user to access/modify the moderator data.

Note that none of these prevents the users from authenticating. Authentication in Firebase is nothing more than entering your credentials to prove that you are you. Granting access to resources based on who you are, known as *authorization*, is up to the application, hence including it in your client-side code, and server-side code or security rules.